# Illegal invocation of javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, google-chrome, runtime-error

```
Dim bot As Selenium.ChromeDriver                                                                             
 Public Sub WebTest()
    Set bot = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim kys As New SeleniumWrapper.keys, arr(), i As Long
    arr = Application.Transpose(Selection)
    With bot
        .Get "https://www.gandhi.com.mx/", -1, True
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(i)) Then
                If i > 1 Then
                 .ExecuteScript "window.open('https://www.gandhi.com.mx/')"
                End If
                .FindElementByCss("[name=q]").SendKeys arr(i)
                .SendKeys bot.keys.Enter
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub
```

This is the whole code and i'm assigning the same to a button in excel. The code works fine while opening two or three chrome tabs and shows the below error.

> javascript error
>   javascript error: illegal invocation

I have tried using `Application.SendKeys ("^t")` and its working. But I could not navigate to any other window while my macro running. If I navigate Ctrl+t works on that application. And i'm getting WindowNotFound Error.

And also I tried using webdriver to open new chrome tab as shown below and it doesn't work.

```
bot.SendKeys kys.Control, "t"
```

Comment: Hi, you need to add some detail to your question, and also who what you have tried so far? also, it's important to share some more code to give people context and help, maybe its the 'URL here' the par failing, or another inner component? you almost might be swallowing some exception that lies underneath

Comment: I have edited my post in brief and added more details about it.

Comment: Hi @aya ranji if you add @ before a user's name, we get notified faster, regarding your code, add a try-catch to see if you can get some more detail, sorry can't provide more help, its been ages since I touched VB